# Grafana: Calculating single value growth percentage from sum(series)

Tags: graphite, grafana

Given a set of series `aaa.bbb.*.ccc`. I need to sum up all series, and show a single value - the percentage increase of LAST value compared to the last available value 1 month ago. In other words:  `(last_now - last_1m_ago) / last_1m_ago`.  I know I can "Override relative time" with "1M" value, but single number calculation escapes me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'll want something like:

```
asPercent(sumSeries(aaa.bbb.*.ccc), timeShift(sumSeries(aaa.bbb.*.ccc), "1mon"))
```

Comment: Will I want to limit the series to something like "1d" or "2d" in the "override relative time"? Also, do I need to use summarize( ,, latest) ?